# Unable to display dynamic data into bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting some data from backend server and trying to put in the bootstrap table every 5 seconds. It is not able to display in table although I can clearly see the json object coming from backend in my console. I tried using refresh, load and append as well as first argument to bootstrapTable function but it is not helping. I want the new data to append to existing data when it comes from the backend in json format but the table is displaying as completely empty in the UI.

Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getUpdates();

function getUpdates() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/getUpdates",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (output) {

           // var $table = $('#table');
            $('#table1').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                data: output
            });
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", output);  //this display correctly in console

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var json = "<h4>Response:</h4><pre>"
                + e.responseText + "</pre>";

            console.log("ERROR : ", e +"Response Text: "+ e.responseText);
          //  $("#btn-update").prop("disabled", false);

        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(getUpdates, 5000); // The interval set to 5 seconds
        }  
    });
    };
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Updates through messaging</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container" style="min-height: 500px">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>CDC Consumer Example </h1>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="table1" data-height="450">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id">Id</th>
                        <th data-field="oldValue">Old Value</th>
                        <th data-field="newValue">New Value</th>
                        <th data-field="tableName">Table Name</th>
                        <th data-field="columnName">Column Name</th>  
                        <th data-field="timestamp">Timestamp</th>          
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript"src="webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/entry.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please show some sample data that you want to show in bootstrap-table

Comment: The sample json payload [{id: 6521761346336240000,
columnName: "sys_role_cd",
newValue: "PARTY",
oldValue: "PART",
tableName: "entries",
timestamp: 1555015719733}]

Answer (score 1):

from looking at that libraries [documentation](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#methods/refresh.html) I don't think that's how the refresh method works.

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#table1').bootstrapTable({ 
    url: '/getUpdates', 
    onLoadSuccess(data) { 
        setTimeout(getUpdates, 5000) 
    }
  })
  function getUpdates() {
    $('#table1').bootstrapTable('refresh')
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `load` not `refresh` in `$('#table1').bootstrapTable('refresh',{data: output});` and just give your new data as a second parameter, for better understand you can see my example below(it's load every 5 seconds):

```js
var mydata = [
 { id: 6521761346336241, 
   columnName: "sys_role_cd1", 
   newValue: "PARTY1", 
   oldValue: "PART1", 
   tableName: "entries1", 
   timestamp: 15550157197331
 }];

$('#table1').bootstrapTable({data: mydata});

window.setInterval(function(){
  //you can call your ajax and reload your table here
  $(function () {
    mydata.push({ 
       id: 6521761346336242, 
       columnName: "sys_role_cd2", 
       newValue: "PARTY2", 
       oldValue: "PART2", 
       tableName: "entries2", 
       timestamp: 15550157197332
    });
    $('#table1').bootstrapTable('load',mydata);
  });
  //console.log("data reload",mydata);
}, 5000);
// to stop this loop you can use `clearInterval()`
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div class="container" style="min-height: 500px">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>CDC Consumer Example </h1>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="table1" data-height="450">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id">Id</th>
                        <th data-field="oldValue">Old Value</th>
                        <th data-field="newValue">New Value</th>
                        <th data-field="tableName">Table Name</th>
                        <th data-field="columnName">Column Name</th> 
                        <th data-field="timestamp">Timestamp</th>   
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: @Amol Aggarwal you can see my answer now, i edit it.

Comment: why bootstrapTable function is getting called twice in the code?

Comment: one for first time and another for loop, it's just for understand, you can use what you need

Comment: @Amol Aggarwal, is it not accept answer for your question?

Comment: No it didn't work for me. I had to manually populate each cell using plain html.